# solving $A=BCD$ for $C$, where $A,B,C,D$ are all matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A,B,C,D$ are all matrices and $A=BCD$ (with dimensions such that all matrix multiplications are defined), how does one solve for $C$?

In the particular context I'm working in, $B$ and $D$ are both orthogonal, and $C$ is diagonal. I'm not sure if that's necessary to solve for $C$.

Comment: Do you know what an inverse matrix is?

Comment: Yes, and I knew that matrix multiplication in general isn't commutative, but it didn't occur to me that you could "pre-" and "post-" multiply both sides of the equation. I've never taken a linear algebra course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to multiply by $B^{-1}$ on the left on each side of the equation which would cancel $B$ on the right, and then by $D^{-1}$ on the right on each side, which would cancel $D$, like this:
$$\begin{align}A&=BCD\\B^{-1}A&=B^{-1}BCD\\B^{-1}A&=CD\\B^{-1}AD^{-1}&=CDD^{-1}\\B^{-1}AD^{-1}&=C\end{align}$$

Comment: $B$ and $D$ are orthogonal, so you can substitute the transpose for the inverse.

Comment: $B^T=B^{-1}$, so it's really just a matter of whether you'd rather write $^T$ or $^{-1}$, since they can be calculated exactly the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- $B^TB=I$
- $DD^T = I$
- You might like to premultiply and postmultiply the equation by some matrices to isolate $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $B, D$ are orthogonal,

$B^t B = D D^t = I$

multiply your equation with $B^t$ from the left and by $D^t$ from the right to get
$$C = B^t A D^t$$